# Open file dialog box

Tags: c#

I wanna use the open file dialog box to choose a folder.

Comment: you can open the folderbrowserdiolag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) instead.